# Understanding rovibrational spectrum for molecules

Tags: atomic-physics, spectroscopy

If we have a roto-vibrational spectrum like the one in the image, the lines on the right are called "R branch" and the lines on the left "P branch". I have one question:

1. All $\Delta J=+1$ $\Delta \nu=+1$ absorption transitions give raise to R-branch lines, in this spectrum do we see in R-branch lines also "jumps" from $\nu=1$ to $\nu=2$ and similar so that $\Delta J=+1$ and $\Delta \nu=+1$ or only from $\nu=0$ to $\nu=1$ so that $\Delta J=+1$ and $\Delta \nu=+1$?

I'm confused beacuse of the second image since I only see in R-branch transitions from $\nu=0$ to $\nu=1$ but from the definition I think I just need to have $\Delta J=+1$ $\Delta \nu=+1$ for R-branch so even $\nu=8$ to $\nu=9$ will give raise to R-branch if $\Delta J=+1$.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first diagram of relative intensity vs wavenumber shows only the $v=0$ to $v=1$ transitions. At the this temperature the population of molecules in the $v=1$ state available to make the $v=1$ to $v=2$ transition is tiny.

In practice, if the variational frequency is sufficiently small that there is enough poulation in the $v=1$ to generate an observable absorption spectrum, these lines will be in a slightly different place because the potential is not perfectly harmonic. This second displaced set of lines is usually called a hot band because it is stronger at higher temperature,